# Chef recipe not executing a specific version

Tags: chef-infra

Team, I have multiple versions of cookbook in my chef server. When I trying to pin a specific version of the cookbook to be executed on the chef node its not executing the recipes for that version.
I have a cookbook with version starting from 0.0.1 till 0.0.20. I am able to see all the versions when I execute the command: `knife cookbook list | awk '{printf "knife cookbook show %s\n",$1}'| bash`

Command I used to pin the version: `sudo chef-client -o "recipe[mycookbook@0.0.15]"`
I even tried `sudo chef-client -o recipe["mycookbook@0.0.15"]`

There are no errors reported in the chef execution.

The environment file on this node is pinned to the version as: `"cookbook_versions": { "mycookbook": "> 0.0.10" },`

if I execute the command: `sudo chef-client` its taking the latest version which is `0.0.20` and running the latest recipes.

Can anyone tell me why the command(s) to pin a previous version are not executing?

Comment: When you execute with `mycookbook@0.0.15` does it run that version as expected? Also, `0.0.20` is indeed `> 0.0.10` which you have pinned in the environment, so I don't see anything amiss there.

Comment: @seshadri_c when I execute the command: `sudo chef-client -o "recipe[mycookbook@0.0.15]"` with env file having `> 0.0.10` I see the cookbook resolve to 0.0.15 but it did not execute the recipes as per the version 0.0.15.

Comment: So, it is picking up the correct version, but you suspect the contents. You can debug further using `knife` sub-commands, e.g. view the recipe as available on Chef server: `knife cookbook show mycookbook 0.0.15 recipes default.rb` (or any recipes of that cookbook).

Comment: run `chef-client --log_level verbose`, it will give you more details